# How does react suspense determine if a component is ready to render

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense, react-lazy-load

I am using `<React.Suspense>` for data fetching like in this [blog post](https://dev.to/smitterhane/swap-out-useeffect-with-suspense-for-data-fetching-in-react-2leb).
From the [react docs](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#what-is-suspense-exactly)

> Suspense lets your components **wait** for something before they can render.

And even better explained in this [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense)

> `React.Suspense` lets you specify the loading indicator in case some components in the tree below it are not yet ready to render

I have understood that a loading indicator specified as fallback prop in `<React.Suspense>` is displayed if a component is not ready to render.

However I am not understanding how React is checking if a component is ready to render or not. According to this [docs](https://17.reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html#approach-3-render-as-you-fetch-using-suspense)

> **As more data streams in, React will retry rendering, and each time it might be able to progress “deeper”.**

Does this mean React also re-renders when data streams in from a network request?
And is `<React.Suspense>` constantly checking if a component is ready to render or not?

Answer (score 3):

`React.Suspense` relies on [Promise](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp) with a special wrapper. Practically, we use [React.lazy](https://react.dev/reference/react/lazy) as the wrapper. If you interested to understand how the wrapper works, see the snippet below.

```js
// Boilerplate for the snippet, usually live in index.js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


// Main Component
function App() {
  return (
    <React.Suspense fallback={<LoadingPage />}>
      <RealPage />
    </React.Suspense>
  );
}

// Promise need to be monitored with a wrapper
function wrapPromise(promise) {
  let status = "pending";
  let result;
  let suspender = promise.then(
    (r) => {
      status = "success";
      result = r;
    },
    (e) => {
      status = "error";
      result = e;
    }
  );
  return {
    read() {
      if (status === "pending") {
        throw suspender;
      } else if (status === "error") {
        throw result;
      } else if (status === "success") {
        return result;
      }
    },
  };
}

// This is an example of a delayed process that
// uses `promise` to mock resource fetch
function delayedProcessExample() {
  // Wait for 3 seconds
  let promise = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))
    // Return an example result
    .then(() => "Hello, World!");

  return promise;
}

// The delayed process should be executed somewhere.
// If you put it in a component, then the App going to
// request indefinitely
const exampleResource = wrapPromise(delayedProcessExample());

// This is how you access the resource
function RealPage() {
  const exampleData = exampleResource.read();
  return <div>{exampleData}</div>;
}

// This is the fallback component
function LoadingPage() {
  return <div>Loading... Please Wait</div>;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Notice the wrapper throws `suspender` promise. That expression tells the `React.Suspend` there is a promise which need to be waited. Thus, basically `React.Suspend` depends on Promise as an Exception to wait the data.

Sources:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-hermann-bztrp?file=/src/index.js
- https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/packages/react/src/ReactLazy.js
- (Deprecated, but conceptually still useful) https://www.johno.com/introduction-to-react-suspense